# Raising and Lowering operators acting on a tensor product of oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I refer to this paper: "[Quantum source of entropy for black holes](http://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Eosegu/Quantum_Entropy.pdf)" by L Bombelli et al. On the fourth page, there is an expression for the state of two coupled oscillators, $a$ and $b$ (equation $12$):

$$\lvert \psi \rangle = C e^{\gamma a^{\dagger} b^{\dagger}} \lvert 0 \rangle_{a} \otimes \lvert 0 \rangle_{b} = C \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\gamma^{n} \lvert n \rangle_{a} \otimes \lvert n \rangle_{b}$$

$C = (1-\gamma^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a normalization constant.

Now, in equation $15$, the authors claim that:

$$a \lvert \psi \rangle = \gamma b^{\dagger} \lvert \psi \rangle, \ \ \ \ b \lvert \psi \rangle = \gamma a^{\dagger} \lvert \psi \rangle \  .$$

How do they get these equations?

Comment: With due respect: do you really expect people will read an significant portion of this paper before answering?  Hint: $e^{-\alpha a^\dagger}ae^{\alpha a^\dagger}=\ldots$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without giving a look into the paper, I will provide my attempt for the answer, as I have been working with creation/annihilation exponential operators and perhaps you will find what I have to say useful. If not, please comment and I will have a quick look at the paper and get back to you.

So, my suggestion is to use an identity regarding the commutator of the exponential operators $e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}$ with the annihilation operators (I take it that $a$ corresponds to annihilating a species of bosons and $b$ corresponds to annihilating another species of bosons. Even if this is not the case, you can still apply the techniques I will describe). So, the identity I will give you can be proven by Taylor expanding the exponential creation operators
$$[a,e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}]=\gamma b^{\dagger} e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}$$
$$[b,e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}]=\gamma a^{\dagger} e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}$$
So, acting on the states $|\psi\rangle$ yields
$$a|\psi\rangle=aCe^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}
|0\rangle_a\otimes|0\rangle_b=
C[a,e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}]|0\rangle_a\otimes|0\rangle_b+
Ce^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}a|0\rangle_a\otimes|0\rangle_b$$
where the last term vanishes, as it involves the annihilation operator acting on the vacuum state for $a$! The first term results in the final result, whose derivation you wish to understand
$$a|\psi\rangle=C[a,e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}]
|0\rangle_a\otimes|0\rangle_b=
\gamma b^{\dagger}e^{\gamma a^{\dagger}b^{\dagger}}
|0\rangle_a\otimes|0\rangle_b=
\gamma b^{\dagger}|\psi\rangle$$

So, the first identity is proven. The same line of reasoning holds for the other. If there are any questions, please comment.

Comment: Please do not provide complete answer to such obvious assignment questions.

Comment: Hi @ZeroTheHero. Sorry if I am being naive here, but isn't the point of the website helping others understand? Maybe it is something that it is not so obvious for the OP, afterall... no?

Comment: helping yes.  doing all the work for them no.

Comment: See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14122/we-shouldnt-answer-homework-question-directly-should-we or https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13422/how-to-answer-homework-like-questions  for instance.

Comment: So, okay, I think I see what you are referring to. To be honest, I didn't think of it as a HW exercise, as it was not formulated as one. I was familiar with that concept of not doing HW for others, I just didn't think that this was such a case (still not 100% convinced to be honest). Moreover, it seems pretty self-contained to me. Anyhow, how should I proceed now? Shall I erase my answer somehow?

Comment: not point in deleting, just beware of providing overly complete answers to this type of assignment-like question.  Don’t get me wrong: it’s a cute question, so much so that I may use it in my class, just don’t give everything away so easily.

Comment: Okay @ZeroTheHero I have noted your suggestion. Thanks! I will be more cautious next time :)